# In NHibernate, how to delete all elements of an associated set?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Let's say I have a class named Parent, in my hbm.xml there is a one-to-many set of the Child class. I want to delete all children of a given parent as efficiently as possible. This is what I'm doing now:

```
foreach (var child in parent1.Children)
    session.Delete(child);
parent1.Children.Clear();
```

This results in 3+ different SQL statements: a SELECT that fetches the children entities, followed by an UPDATE that sets the foreign key in all children to NULL based on the parent foreign key, followed by multiple DELETE statements, one by one.

What I would like to see is one DELETE that deletes all children, based on their parent foreign key. Is there an NHibernate way to do that? Or do I need to bite the bullet and issue a raw SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NHibernate introduced a very cool feature: [13.3. DML-style operations](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#batch-direct).

This supports two NHibernate/SQL features at one:

1. Using HQL on top of the **mapped** model *(we are working with our Entity/POCO model)*
2. executing the WRITE operations directly on the server *(NO data download to app server)*

Adjust example from documentation mentioned above:

```
ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
ITransaction tx = session.BeginTransaction();

String hqlDelete = "delete Children c where c.ParentId = :parentId";

int deletedEntities = s.CreateQuery( hqlDelete )
        .SetString( "parentId", parentId )
        .ExecuteUpdate();
tx.Commit();
session.Close();
```

Nice reading: [Ayende: NHibernate – Executable DML](http://ayende.com/blog/4037/nhibernate-executable-dml)

Comment: The child entity has no parent property, it is not mapped in hbm.xml either. The association is only defined in the parent. Can I do this delete from the parents point of view, or do I have to map the inverse many-to-one association as well?

Comment: I discussed that many times, so I am *almost* sure, that we should mapp the ParentId on the child entity. First... it is on the Child table, so it belongs to the Child by the nature. Second, that brings lot of advantages, e.g. DML ;). We can still reduce the WRITE operations (e.g. make Parent just Readonly `insert/update="false"`), We can make the `ParentId` property with protected setter... etc. The point on the other hand is, that we did gain a lot of freedom (we can do Subqueries now either)